# How to change output device when using AVSampleBufferAudioRenderer to play the audio?

Tags: swift, xcode, audio, avfoundation

I am rendering audio from received input as in code:

```
...
let bufferRenderSyncer = AVSampleBufferRenderSynchronizer() 
let bufferRenderer = AVSampleBufferAudioRenderer()
...
func captureOutput(_ output: AVCaptureOutput, didOutput sampleBuffer: CMSampleBuffer, from connection: AVCaptureConnection) {
            bufferRenderer.enqueue(sampleBuffer)
            
            if bufferRenderSyncer.rate == 0 {
                bufferRenderSyncer.setRate(1, time: sampleBuffer.presentationTimeStamp)
            }
        }
...
```

and it works great with or without headset (I speak to mike on iPhone or on headset and hear myself from the related speaker eg on iPhone or headset)

but I need to use mike on headset and the output device to be switchable between headset, speaker or another connected headset (airpods)

I have not find any source saying how to change output device (from default) using bufferRenderer.. any suggestions?